# Draw control selection rectangle with resize points in windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I want to draw a rectangle with the resize points for the selected control as shown in the image below.

[image]

I made use of the paint event of the control and i was able to draw a border rectangle for the selected control.

```
 Rectangle borderRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
 ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, borderRectangle, Color.Black,System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBorderStyle.Dotted);
```

Do we have any option to include the functionality as we have in the windows forms designer?

Please do suggest me a method for the same.

Thanks in Advance,

K

Comment: You can check the possible explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039883/how-can-i-draw-a-square-around-an-object-like-this-in-my-gui-editor/13040680#13040680

Comment: @Nick Thank you for the post Nick. It gave me an idea how it can be done.

Comment: It's Ok, I didn't want to type that answer again when I have the similar on the other question ;-)

Comment: You already found ControlPaint, the squares are drawn with its DrawGrabHandle() method.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes. The DrawGrabHandle method with a rectangle for the edge worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a custom implementation to have resizable controls on codeproject:

[Allow the User to Resize Controls at Runtime](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20716/Allow-the-User-to-Resize-Controls-at-Runtime)

And here is some official information on how to build a full-fledged form designer in .NET:

[Tailor Your Application by Building a Custom Forms Designer with .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163871.aspx)

Comment: I tried with the example as shown in code project. But for my case it doesn't work. I am not sure where I am going wrong. In my case I have a Panel control as the holder and a button (for example) on the panel. The border appears inside the control.